# Objective-C Find and Replace String problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

im trying to do a find and replace on a string to do

```
tempString =[tempString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"""];
```

but it does not work with the """, is there anyway i can wrap the quote so i can use it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried a backslash before the second `"`? A la:

```
tempString = [tempString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\""];
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind , have sorted the issue

```
tempString =[tempString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\""];
```

thanks for looking :)

Comment: You should really award the answer to @fbrereto who answered correctly at exactly the same time as you :)